# How to disable past dates in material-ui Date picker?

Tags: material-ui

I'm using material-ui Date-Picker. How to disable past days before today's date?

```
 import React from 'react';
 import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';

function disablePastDays(date) {
  //code here to disable past days
}

const calendar = () => (
    <div>
        <DatePicker shouldDisableDate={disablePastDays}/>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 40):

material-ui's DatePicker accepts `minDate` prop. So you might want this:

```
const today = new Date();
<DatePicker minDate={today}/>
```

Comment: Thank you wesley6j

Comment: Might be best to put this outside of render else a new date is created on every render.

Comment: Nice !! Thanks :)

Answer (score 23):

Use `disablePast`.

```
<DatePicker
    disablePast
/>
```

They have it since [v1.0.0-beta.10](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/material-ui-pickers/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.10).

Comment: that doesn't also disable the time

Comment: This is great. Worked for me to display only current and future dates.

Comment: Works for MUI version V5.5.2

Comment: useful for me. Tks

Answer (score 3):

We can give minDate as props to the DatePicker material UI component

Create a state using usestate and then pass the state value into the props as below

```
const [startMinDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date())

<DatePicker
      required
      label="Date"
      disablePast                  
      minDate = {startMinDate}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using i**mport DatePicker from '@mui/lab/DatePicker';** library of version **"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.66"**

Below code works fine for me

```
 <DatePicker
   disablePast
   value={checkout.rideDate}
   onChange={(newValue) => { // your code of onChange functionality}
    />
   }
 />
```